# when i write requestWindowFeature(window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); at that time i am getting error on window tag

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
```

i also added the package import android.view.Window;
but still i'm getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting that before the call to super, I've had to do that before.

Anothing thing to try is setting `android:windowActionBarOverlay=` to true in you app theme.

Or you could also try using `getWindow().requestFeature();`